# Updatepanel with ajaxcontroltoolkit postback issue on Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ajax, updatepanel, distributedcache

We have an custom web part that stores some information in the view state, and uses Update Panels.

We have rare, intermittent bug that occurs in SharePoint 2013 only whereby sometimes, after button click (that should trigger a partial refresh via an Updatepanel), the page goes back to its initial state.

We were able to reproduce the bug by stopping/starting the distributed cache service while working with the page.

So, first of all, is this likely the culprit, and second, is it possible to disable the ViewStateCache for a web application?

This is end user webpart which has dynamic controls on the form for configuration purpose. To maintain the state of dynamic controls across page post back we are using the ViewState.

To fix the error, we had increase the Request Timeout limit for the relevant cache using the following commands.

```
$ViewStateCache = Get-SPDistributedCacheClientSetting -ContainerType DistributedViewStateCache 
$ViewStateCache.RequestTimeout = 300 
Set-SPDistributedCacheClientSetting -ContainerType DistributedViewStateCache -DistributedCacheClientSettings $ViewStateCache
```

The  above commands won’t help us  to resolve the problem. So if anybody came across the such issue then help appreciated to resolve this issue.

Comment: i have tha same situation. I have researched that it is related with claims based authentication. But i don't know how to resolve it.
I have tried:
- different settings of distributed cache service
- configure SSL
- configure Kerberos But if web application is configured to Classic authentication mode there is now bug. Also you can try to disable Forms Authentication for web application in IIS and check that bug will disappear (but in this case portal will not work ). Have you found any more solutions?